# Google datastore return number of operation used per request?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have been using Amazon's dynamodb for a while and they have an option after a request to return the number of read/write operations used. This way you can see exactly how much each query is taking up and helps to adjust your queries in case you have missed something. I was wondering if Google's datastore had something such as this? Looking through the local datastore docs I could not find this information:

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/devserver

Does something such as this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In development server (`http://127.0.0.1:8888/_ah/admin/datastore`) you can select an entity kind and see how many write operations have been used to store each entity.

Also, in the production logs you can see how much time each call took and how much it costs in USD.

Overall, read/write costs in the Datastore are deterministic, i.e. you can calculate how many operations are required based on the number of entities involved and number of indexed properties in each entity. I agree, though, that it may be useful to visually examine the tools I listed above for unexpected anomalies.

Answer (score 0):

The Google App Engine SDK (Java and Python) includes the Appstats library.

Appstats is a suite of App and API call profiling tools that record events and provide a web-based administrative interface for browsing statistics, such as datastore operations.

Java: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats

Python: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats